# In jquery rest result for person object as a [object Object]

Tags: jquery, listdata.svc, data

Would it be possible to get a Person or Group type as a string rather than and [object Object], I am handling everything within the front-end with REST calls to listdata.svc URL's.

CODE

```
// DISPLAY
// display books on html
function displayBooks(books){
  for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++){
    var s = '<tr><td>' + books[i].CheckedOutTo+ '</td></tr>'; // ** Ends up displaying as [object, Object] 

    $('.LibraryTable').append(s);
  }
 }

// QUERY CALLS / LIST DATA CALLS
// Queries all of the books.
function getBooks(){
  var url = '/tools_services/training_library/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Book';
  var books = new Array();
  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++){
        var book = data.d.results[i];
        books[i] = book;
    }
  });
  return books;
};
```

As where I have `**` I want this code to be displayed for example 'Joe Smith' rather than [object Object]. I also want to be able to check if this field is not initialized.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I needed to change up the URL parameters a bit up to `var url = 'http://portal.internal.urs.org/tools_services/training_library/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Book?$expand=CheckedOutTo';`

I was not joining the two tables correctly, and also reference it by `book.CheckedOutTo.Name`

Answer (score 0):

Try casting this to a `FieldUserValue` and then accessing the `LookupValue` Property.

see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.fielduservalue_members(v=office.14).aspx

and

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380878/how-to-get-sharepoint-user-object-from-the-assignedto-field-using-client-side

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, would it be possible to handle this completely in javascript/jquery, since I am using REST calls and not dealing with the actual backend code.